# ReLU Function In A Recurrent Neural Network. Weights Become Infinity or Zero

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am new to machine learning. I've read that the ReLU function is better than a sigmoid function for a recurrent neural network because of the vanishing gradient problem.

I'm trying to implement a very basic recurrent neural network with 3 input nodes, 10 hidden nodes and 3 output nodes.

There is the ReLU function at both input and hidden nodes and the softmax function for the output nodes.

However when I'm using the ReLU function after few epochs (less than 10) either the error gets to 0 or the error gets to infinity depending on whether the weight changes are added or subtracted from the original weights.

```
weight = weight + gradient_decent #weights hits infinity
weight = weight - gradient decent #weights become 0
```

And also because it hits infinity it gives the following error,

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in maximum
  return np.maximum(x, 0)
```

However when I implement the sigmoid function the error nicely comes down. But because this is a simple example that is fine but if I use it on a bigger problem I am afraid I will hit with the vanishing gradient problem.

Is this caused by the small number of hidden nodes, how can I solve this issue? If you need the code sample please comment, not posting the code because it's too long.

Thank you.

Comment: From what I know, a problem with ReLU is that it can blow up.  So you have to choose which risk to take: vanishing gradient or weights going to infinity.  See [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/211359/101882) related question on Cross Validated.

Comment: @Jason yes I but because it was blowing up every time I was thinking it was my fault, but the number of steps it takes to blow up varies, but definitely less than 10

Comment: Could you provide the code?

Comment: could you also link to source of the claim that "relus are good for RNNs"?

Answer (score 6):

I do not think the number of hidden nodes is the problem.

In the first case the weights are approaching infinity since the gradient descent update is wrong. The gradient of the loss with respect to a weight represents the direction in which you should update the weight in order to increase the loss. Since one (usually) wants to minimize it, if the weights are updated in the positive direction, they will increase the loss and very likely leading to divergence.

Despite of that, even if assuming the update is right, I would see it more as wrong initialization/hyperparameter setting rather than a strictly ReLU dependent problem (obviously ReLU explodes in its positive part, giving infinity, while sigmoid saturates, giving 1).

In the second case instead, what is happening is the *dead ReLU* problem, a saturated ReLU that gives always the same (zero) output and it is not able to recover itself. It could happen for many reasons (i.e. bad initialization, wrong bias learning) but the most probable is a too high update step. Try to decrease your learning rate and see what happens.

In case this does not solve the problem, think to use the *Leaky ReLU* version, also just for simply debugging purposes.

More (and better explained) details about the *Leaky ReLU* and the *dead ReLU* can be found here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/what-is-the-dying-relu-problem-in-neural-networks

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I did not use a bias in this case because the rnn is small, maybe adding a bias can solve the problem? The learning rate for this was 0.15 :)

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on @lemm-ras's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38907274/957657), [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.03771) by Talathi and Vartak shows that the initial value of the recurrent weight matrix will strongly influence the performance of a recurrent neural network with reLU activation. Specifically, the authors demonstrate that a network of recurrent units with ReLU activation will perform best when the recurrent weight matrix is initialized so that it is positive definite, with the largest eigenvalue equal to one and all other eignenvalues less than one. Their explanation is that the way the network weights evolve over time is dependent on the initial condition of the network (shown in Figure 2 of Talathi and Vartak), and can lead to a few different cases:

Case 1: If all eigenvalues are one, then the network starts at a stable condition and does not evolve over time (Figure 2a)

Case 2: If all eigenvalues are less than one the network is attracted toward the origin and the network will always evolve toward a recurrent weight matrix of zero (Figure 2b).

Case 3: If any eignevalues are greater than one the network does not have a stable attractor, and will "blow up" (Figure 2d).

Case 4: If the recurrent weight matrix has one eigenvalue of one and the rest are less than one, then there can be a stable manifold that the network will evolve toward, and it can reach a stable, non-zero solution (Figure 2c). I don't know if this is guaranteed to be true for all problems, so I believe it'd be best to think of this as a necessary but not proven to be sufficient condition.

From the initial question, it sounds like @rksh's problem is the second case, and the network is attracted toward zero. Try initializing the weight matrix as Talathi and Vartak suggest and see if that addresses the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I needed to use `sigmoid` on the outputs and cap `relu` at 6. In other words:

```
f(x) = min(max(0, x), 6)
```